# Using csv module inside class in Python

Tags: python, csv, object

I try to create a class which will use csv module in one of it's method.

```
import csv
print(csv.__file__)

class CSV_Processing:

    def __init__(self,file):
        self.file = file

    def csv_init(self, csv_content={}):

        with open(self.file) as csv_file:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
            line_count = 0
            for row in csv_reader:
                csv_content[str(line_count)] = row
                line_count += 1
            print(csv_content)

csv = CSV_Processing('CSV_file.csv')
csv.csv_init()
```

Somehow I got error.

> AttributeError: 'CSV_Processing' object has no attribute 'reader'

How should I initialize module in the class?

Comment: Your indentation is off in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You overrided `csv` module by defining a variable with `csv` name.
change:

```
csv = CSV_Processing('CSV_file.csv')
```

to

```
another_name = CSV_Processing('CSV_file.csv')
```

when you import csv and create a variable with the same name, you will override its functionality indeed.

Comment: Your welcome @iczyrski, Please consider this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers